# How to resize WebView according to its content?

Tags: cocoa, webview

I want to set simple html contents within a web view and then resize it according to its content.

To set simple html contents within web view I used this code and it is working fine:

```
[[myWebView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:webViewContents baseURL:baseURLFramed];
```

Right now, if content is more than its actual size then it appears in web view showing both vertical and horizontal scroller in it. I want to set some default width and manage height according to its content in a way so that neither horizontal nor vertical scroller appears.

Can anyone suggest me some solution for it?

Thanks,

Miraaj

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can register as the `WebView`'s frame load delegate, and when the page loads you can ask the main frame's document view for its size and resize the `WebView`. Make sure you turn off scrollbars on the frame or you will have problems.

Be aware that certain pages can be very large, when I tested daringfireball.net it came in at 17612 points high, which is obviously too large to display on-screen.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification 
{
    //set ourselves as the frame load delegate so we know when the window loads
    [webView setFrameLoadDelegate:self];

    //turn off scrollbars in the frame
    [[[webView mainFrame] frameView] setAllowsScrolling:NO];

    //load the page
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://daringfireball.net"]];
    [[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
}

//called when the frame finishes loading
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)webFrame
{
    if([webFrame isEqual:[webView mainFrame]])
    {
        //get the rect for the rendered frame
        NSRect webFrameRect = [[[webFrame frameView] documentView] frame];
        //get the rect of the current webview
        NSRect webViewRect = [webView frame];

        //calculate the new frame
        NSRect newWebViewRect = NSMakeRect(webViewRect.origin.x, 
                                           webViewRect.origin.y - (NSHeight(webFrameRect) - NSHeight(webViewRect)), 
                                           NSWidth(webViewRect), 
                                           NSHeight(webFrameRect));
        //set the frame
        [webView setFrame:newWebViewRect];

        //NSLog(@"The dimensions of the page are: %@",NSStringFromRect(webFrameRect));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx Rob... I have implemented it and it is working fine.. but there is one problem: it is always setting the highest height for the webview which I am getting for different contents.. ie. if height was 1029.0 and now it should be 339.0 then it is appending space at end and showing web view with height 1029.0

Comment: Rob the problem is now resolved .. before setting its contents I am now resizing web view to some default and smaller values... say, (15.0, 0.0, 560.0, 10.0).. I must say Rob Rocks!

Comment: When I change the DOM during some interaction in the WebView which triggers a change the dimensions of the visible area of it this method  `webView:didFinishLoadForFrame` won't be called again, true? Is there some delegate that will be called in this case? BTW: Your solution did not work for me. Maybe you can help out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21992854/1146700)?

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to ask the DOM for the height of your content.

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
{
    NSString*   heightOutput    = [sender stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"foo\").scrollHeight;"];
    NSInteger   height          = [heightOutput integerValue];

    [[self splitView] setPosition:height + 10 ofDividerAtIndex:0];
}
```

The key point here is to place your content inside of a named element so getElementById can be used. My implementation used a simple `<div id="foo">` element.

In my particular case, my WebView was inside of a NSSplitView, so first resetting the height of the WebView to something small was causing a flicker.

I've got a sample project [here](https://github.com/ericgorr/WebViewTest.git) demonstrating it.

Comment: This works better for me than `[[[webFrame frameView] documentView] frame]` because it always returns proper value. I don't know why, but `documentView.frame` works only when a page is loaded for the first time, otherwise it returns empty size (maybe bacause of caching).

Comment: Indeed, @Darrarski - this even works after the frame resized gor resized, i.e its width changed, causing the content height to change as well, whereas the accepted answer does not help in that case as it keeps reporting the initial size.