# How do I find the height of a WebView's content at the current width?

Tags: cocoa, webview, webkit

I want to resize my WebView vertically to fit its content. How do I find out what the best height is?

I tried looking at the WebFrame's frameView, but that's just the size of the view it's being displayed in, and `[frameView intrinsicContentSize]` always returns -1, -1.

**Update:**

I can do this:

`DOMNode *bodyNode = [[[frame DOMDocument] getElementsByTagName:@"body"] item:0];
float scrollHeight = [[bodyNode valueForKey:@"scrollHeight"] floatValue];`

..but the result I get is never less than the height of the WebView, even when the content is plainly shorter.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is here:

[How to resize WebView according to its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675244/how-to-resize-webview-according-to-its-content)

The key is in the comments to the accepted answer: resize the WebView to something small before getting the size.