# Scaling Fixed Content in Cocoa WebView with Mouse Events

Tags: cocoa, webview, mouseevent, nswindow

I have a OSX Cocoa WebView that is a subview of view in a NSViewController.  The view of the NSViewController has been added as a subview to the main window controller's view.

I am attempting to load HTML5 games into the WebView and proportionally scale them so that they fit the WebView with the least empty space possible.

I have a LOT of games I am trying to make this work for with different constraints.

For HTML5 games that were designed to auto-scale to the window, this works perfectly out of the box.

For HTML5 games that were design a fixed size for iPhone, they appear in the upper left of the WebView and take up a very small portion of the window.

For example, many games are 480x360.  The window size is 1024x768 (less the title bar).

I've tried various methods for scaling up the content:
[How to resize WebView according to its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675244/how-to-resize-webview-according-to-its-content)
[Scale WebView in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181587/scale-webview-in-cocoa)

I've also tried using javascript to scale the content.

These definitely DO work in scaling up the content and I can get good results in filling the screen.

HOWEVER, this does NOT properly scale the position of the mouse events on the WebView canvas.  Meaning, no matter how big I scale the WebView clipview which resizes content, the actual area that is clickable with the mouse is still the smaller unscaled area (as if visually things are scaling but functionally things are not).

Is there some way to scale the mouse click event for position?  I can see if I click in the lower right area of the smaller bounding box, it has an affect on the larger scaled content as if I clicked the lower right area.

It seems I could add some scaling math somewhere in capturing the mouse click events but I don't understand where this can be done.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks